# Extra word between date and time with date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I am looking for a way to add an extra word between the date and time in `date-fns` library, but couldn't find such format. Right now I am using `format` function with `MMM d hh:mm aa` format.

The outcome is:
`Nov 15 10:00 PM`

Is there a way to get:
`Nov 15 at 10:00 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd highly recommend reading and understanding the docs, before posting a question as simple as this.

As per [documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format) for the latest version (as of writing `2.29.3`) the following will yield the required result.

`format(new Date("Sep 2 2020 13:00"), "MMM dd 'at' HH:MM a")`